# How to pick the right button within a list with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

I have a list of different servers. So when clicking on the button "connect", I want to connect to that specific server. 
How can I pick the right button with jQuery? Thank you in advance!

```
{% for  server in servers%}
  {% if server.credential.user == user %}
    {% if server.credential.protocol == 'vnc' %}
      <a>
        <div class="p-l-20" id="server_details">
          <h4>{{server.name}}</h4>
          <h6>Hostname: {{server.hostname}}</h6>
          <h6>IP Address: {{server.ip}}</h6>
          <h6>Protocol: {{server.credential.protocol|upper}}</h6>
          <h6>User: {{server.credential.user}}</h6>
          <button type="button" >Connect</button>
        </div>
      </a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you're setting an id to an element inside a look. This means that there could be many elements with that id and that is not allowed. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, remove the parent `<a>` as you cannot have nested clickable elements. Secondly, you're creating numerous elements with the same `id` which is invalid as they must be unique within the DOM. Change `server_details` to a class instead.

To achieve what you require add an event handler to the `button` elements. From there you can traverse the DOM to find the necessary server information. In the example below I added a `span` around the IP address with a class which you can target to read its `text()`, but the pattern is the same for any other details you want to read:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var ip = $(this).closest('.server_details').find('.ip').text();
  console.log(ip);
});
```

```css
.server_details {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-l-20 server_details">
  <h4>{{server.name1}}</h4>
  <h6>Hostname: {{server.hostname1}}</h6>
  <h6>IP Address: <span class="ip">{{server.ip1}}</span></h6>
  <h6>Protocol: {{server.credential.protocol1|upper}}</h6>
  <h6>User: {{server.credential.user1}}</h6>
  <button type="button">Connect</button>
</div>
<div class="p-l-20 server_details">
  <h4>{{server.name2}}</h4>
  <h6>Hostname: {{server.hostname2}}</h6>
  <h6>IP Address: <span class="ip">{{server.ip2}}</span></h6>
  <h6>Protocol: {{server.credential.protocol2|upper}}</h6>
  <h6>User: {{server.credential.user2}}</h6>
  <button type="button">Connect</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It works but I get the IP address when I changed
```var ip = $(this).closest('.server_details').find('.ip').text();
```
to 
```var ip = $(this).closest('div').find('.ip').text();
```

Comment: That sounds like you didn't add the `class` to the parent `div`, but as long as you got it working it's all good. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Comment: I did exactly what you have said but nothing showing up in the browser console using console.log until I change '.server_details' to 'div' as I told you.